How to update wails build?
gregoriusdimas  ~/golang/second-wails    v1.20  07:07  wails build
Wails CLI v2.8.1


# Build Options

Platform(s)        | linux/amd64                                      
Compiler           | /home/gregoriusdimas/.gvm/gos/go1.20/bin/go      
Skip Bindings      | false                                            
Build Mode         | production                                       
Devtools           | false                                            
Frontend Directory | /home/gregoriusdimas/golang/second-wails/frontend
Obfuscated         | false                                            
Skip Frontend      | false                                            
Compress           | false                                            
Package            | true                                             
Clean Bin Dir      | false                                            
LDFlags            |                                                  
Tags               | []                                               
Race Detector      | false                                            

# Building target: linux/amd64

  • Generating bindings: Done.
  • Installing frontend dependencies: Done.
  • Compiling frontend: Done.
  • Compiling application: go build github.com/wailsapp/wails/v2/pkg/assetserver/webview:
# pkg-config --cflags  -- gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0 gio-unix-2.0 gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0 gio-unix-2.0 gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0
pkg-config: exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in $PATH
  ERROR   exit status 1

  ERROR   exit status 1
 ♥   If Wails is useful to you or your company, please consider sponsoring the project:
https://github.com/sponsors/leaanthony

can these go env cause error while running wails build GOMODCACHE="/home/gregoriusdimas/go1.13/pkg/mod" to go1.20 and GOPATH="/home/gregoriusdimas/go1.13" to go1.20?


needs to install pkg-config then other requirements such as:
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pkg-config

pkg-config --version

sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev libglib2.0-dev

make sure that your current go env in proper setup:

export GOMODCACHE="/home/gregoriusdimas/go1.20/pkg/mod"

export GOPATH="/home/gregoriusdimas/go1.20"

source .profile

wails build

gregoriusdimas  ~/golang/second-wails    v1.20  07:22  wails build
Wails CLI v2.8.1
Build Options
Platform(s)        | linux/amd64
Compiler           | /home/gregoriusdimas/.gvm/gos/go1.20/bin/go
Skip Bindings      | false
Build Mode         | production
Devtools           | false
Frontend Directory | /home/gregoriusdimas/golang/second-wails/frontend
Obfuscated         | false
Skip Frontend      | false
Compress           | false
Package            | true
Clean Bin Dir      | false
LDFlags            |
Tags               | []
Race Detector      | false
Building target: linux/amd64
• Generating bindings: Done.
• Installing frontend dependencies: Done.
• Compiling frontend: Done.
• Compiling application: Done.
• Packaging application: Done.
Built '/home/gregoriusdimas/golang/second-wails/build/bin/second-wails' in 29.147s.
♥   If Wails is useful to you or your company, please consider sponsoring the project:
https://github.com/sponsors/leaanthony
